# Is a Python variable type hint required when a new value is assigned?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, pep8

First of all, I know that type hinting is optional in Python - so my question is whether it is required in the sense of meaningfully helping Python completion/linting/etc. tools parse the code. Consider the following minimum example:

```
a: int = 1
a = 3
#---
b: Foo = Foo()
bar = Foo()
b = bar
```

In both cases, the type of the variables `a` and `b` is hinted at declaration, but I do not specify it again when the values change (to different values of the same type). I am wondering for tools like the [Microsoft Language Server for Python](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server), is this "enough" for the tool to determine that `a` is an `int` and `b` is a `Foo` object? The alternative would be to type hint every time that the variable's value changes, which I feel is too laborious:

```
a: int = 3
b: Foo = bar
```

Comment: Surely the answer would depend on the tool in question. It is up to a tool how to use type hints, with simply ignoring the type hints altogether one valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just once in the scope of the name should be fine. (It certainly is for PyCharm's inference, but other dev tools may vary.)

(As an aside, if the type of the data pointed to by that name changes (say from `int` to `str`), that'd be a code smell...)